# Why is there Segmentation Fault in this code

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, segmentation-fault

I was writing a simple code to calculate the factorial of big numbers. I am not finding anything going out of bounds but still getting a segmentation fault. Please let me know if you see anything.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> factorial(int N){
        
        vector<int> fact;
        
        fact.push_back(1);
        
        for(int i=2; i<=N; i++){
            int carry=0;
            int j;
            for(j=0; j<fact.size(); j++){
                int val = fact[j]*i + carry;
                fact[j] = val%10;
                carry = val/10;
            }
            if(carry!=0){
                fact[j] = carry;
            }
        }
        reverse(fact.begin(), fact.end());
    }
```

Comment: Your vector has only one element, so any `fact[j]` when `j > 0` is out of bounds.

Comment: *"I am not finding anything going out of bounds"*  - except the one and only thing that could possibly be indexed out of bounds, and *is*.  If you don't believe that, change all `fact[j]` in this code to `fact.at(j)` and rerun your program.

Comment: Can be fixed like this `if (carry != 0) { fact.push_back(carry); }`

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to `push_back` your results to `fact`, meaning that it will always remain at size '1'.

Furthermore, after your first loop, your `j` will have the value of `1` (`0` within your last iteration of the loop), resulting in you accessing a 'not existing' index in your vector when you check for the carry (outside of your loop).

Comment: `j` will have a value of `1` after the first loop. Still an out of bounds access however.

Comment: Sorry, you are, of course, right.